# SSH key generator for Ubuntu

Tags: ssh

I want to know the best alternative of Puttygen for ubuntu. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ssh-keygen`. More information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys